# Bash A positional argument for directory path

Tags: bash, git-bash

I'm a new bash player, I want to ask how to pass the directory path to bash script in commandline

for example, ./test1.sh ~/test1/test2.  a directory that passes by $1 for counting numbers of files, direcotry in test2.

Comment: arguments from the command line can be accessed inside of the script with `"$1"`, `$2`, `.... etc`. so in your script, you can set a named variable with a value from the cmd-line, i.e. `dirToFix="$1"`, and then `cd "$dirToFix"` or whatever other commands you need. You can of course skip that and say `cd "$1"`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Bash have command

```
# pwd
```

### It's give you directory in start script directory
try it

```
#!/bin/bash 
folder=$(pwd)
echo $folder
```

---

### in last script

```
#!/bin/bash 
cd $1 
folder=$(pwd)
echo $folder
ls | wc -l
```